# Visual Studio "auto" checks out wrong branch when cloning GIT repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, azure-devops

Steps:

Using Google Chrome, I go to our Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (MS VS TFS) website, select a repository, and click on the "Clone" link/button in the upper right corner of the screen.

In the resulting "Clone repo" window, I click on the "Clone in Visual Studio" button.

In the resulting "Open Microsoft Visua...ndler Selector" window, I click on the "Open Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handler Selector" button.

Visual Studio (VS) opens with an "Azure DevOps Server" window, allowing for me to input the local path, which is the destination folder for the clone. I choose to keep the default/provided value for local path, which already has a folder name exactly the same as the repository name.

I click the "Connect" button and wait for the clone process to finish.

When it finally finishes, in the GIT repository and branch info in the bottom right corner of the screen, I can see that VS has "auto" checked out a (seemingly random?) branch instead of the branch marked as *default* in our MS VS TFS.

We have several old branches that we're keeping for the moment, all of which begin with "DO_NOT_USE...", and for some reason (???) it selects one of those instead of the *default* branch.

**So, how can I get VS to behave as expected and "auto" check out the *default* branch instead?**

Versions:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 16.9.3
- Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 15.117.27414.0

Comment: You might want to consider shortening your question. It would increase your chances of a quick answer

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue with Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 15.117.27414.0, but could not reproduce it with Azure DevOps Service and Azure DevOps Server.

You could either upgrade your TFS 2017 to the latest Azure DevOps Server, or switch the branch manually.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?